# Use ML kit to scan pictures

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-mlkit

Can I use Firebase ML Kit (Face Recognition) to scan pictures for faces and determine if faces are found, log a user into an account? What I mean is verify that a face is found on the picture and sign a user up. Anyone?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, your question may be getting downvotes because it did not attend the basic principles for asking a question on this website. Please take a look at these links to understand why: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't worry, just delete the question to get rid of downvotes and post a new one which attends the standard.

Comment: But is there a way ML Kit can achieve this feat?

Comment: Sorry that you've had a bad experience with down votes Gabriel. Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase ML Kit can perform face **detection**. It does however **not** perform face **recognition**.

In other words: it can tell you that there is a face in a picture (and where it is), but it can't tell you who it is.

This makes it impossible to use ML Kit for authenticating a user.

Comment: Downvoter: can you please explain why you downvoted?

Comment: Okay that was very helpful. That was the exact answer I wanted. I tried this and it worked. I just want to detect faces in pictures users will upload and then sign them in. It is prerequisite for signing up. You have to upload a portrait of yourself. And ML Kit did an amazing job with just a few lines of code. Thanks again @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Okay @Frank van Puffelen Definitely!